# Ordenar datos en componente con tabla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Tengo este componente que es la respuesta de una API que la pinto en una tabla con tres columnas: `title`, `location` y `type`. En el encabezado de la columna de `title` tengo un botón al que le aplico una función `onSortChange` para modificar el orden de dicha columna.
Me cambia el nombre del botón pero no me hace altera el orden.
¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

```js
class Jobs extends React.Component {

  state = {
    currentSort: 'default'
  };

  onSortChange = () => {
    const { currentSort } = this.state;
    let nextSort;

    if (currentSort === 'down') nextSort = 'up';
    else if (currentSort === 'up') nextSort = 'default';
    else if (currentSort === 'default') nextSort = 'down';

    this.setState({
      currentSort: nextSort
    });
  };


  render() {
    const { jobs } = this.props;
    const { currentSort } = this.state;
    const sortTypes = {
      up: {
        className: 'sort-up',
        fn: (a, b) => a.jobs - b.jobs
      },
      down: {
        className: 'sort-down',
        fn: (a, b) => b.jobs - a.jobs
      },
      default: {
        className: 'sort',
        fn: (a, b) => a
      }
    };
    return (      
      jobs.length > 0 && (
      <div className="col">
        <table className="table table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th >Title
                <button onClick={this.onSortChange}>
                  {sortTypes[currentSort].className}
                </button>
                </th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>TYPE OF WORK DAY</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
          {[...jobs].sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn).map(item => (
              <tr>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
                  <td>{item.location}</td>
                  <td>{item.type}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    ));
  }
}

const data=[
  {location:'A',jobs: 23, type: 'AA'},
  {location:'B',jobs: 13, type: 'A'},
  {location:'C',jobs: 22, type: 'AB'}
];
ReactDOM.render(<Jobs jobs={data}/>, document.getElementById('div1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Israel, he creado un fragmento con tu código para que se viese más fácil lo que intentas hacer... y me funciona. Debes tener un error en otro lado o tus datos están mal

Comment: Buenas Pablo Lozano, al parecer el dato que me venía no era numérico por ello la lógica no me podía funcionar. Hice un simulacro de dato numérico con math. random para generar el efecto que intentaba buscar. Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia.